# How to access json from Rest API

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am returning data from a rest API. I was getting the header along with the json, but as Justin T. pointed out below I needed to add this to my cURL:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

That got rid of the header. Now I am having issue with the returned json and the encoding of it(I think)

```
if ( $httpCode != 200 )
{
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n".curl_error($ch);
} 
 else {
    $output = json_encode($result);
    echo($output);
}
```

and my jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type:$('#BTA_AddUser').attr('method'),
    url: form.action,
    data: dataString,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        if(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
        } else {
            $('#response').html('<p>no response</p>');
        }
    }
});
```

This prints out the returned json on the page:

```
{"code":"UserUpdated","status":200,"message":"OK","payload":{"email":"test@test.com","expired":null,"funded":true}}
```

however, I cannot access the json objects, using

```
success:function(data){
    if(data.code == "UserUpdated"){
     //do something
    }
}
```

It defaults to the else clause, not doing what is inside when looking for data.code

Comment: I didn't down vote.

Comment: Also, `working curl stuff above` doesn't give us a good hint of what's happening above.

Comment: @vivek_23, in the OP's defense, I believe they intentionally omitted the 'working curl stuff' because they did not want to post more code than was necessary. If they had suspected the issue was with the curl options, I am sure they would have posted it and not labeled it as 'working'. That being said, I still had enough information to know what they needed to do to resolve the issue...

Comment: I should have put the curl options, my bad @vivek_23. Justin was able to gather what he needed. I'll do better. Thanks guys. Having other issues accessing the json, strange stuff.

Comment: @vivek_23 Please see updated question

Comment: @JustinT.  That's not how it works. OP needs to show a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to help us reproduce the issue and help OP to fix it.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Is the response you are getting from the API already in JSON? If yes, why are you encoding into JSON again?

Comment: I removed the json encode, I can console.log(data['code']) and it will show the code, but I can't run an if / else in the success handler like if(data.code == "UserUpdated") -> do something

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign you will have to tag me else I won't be notified.  What does `console.log( typeof data);` and `console.log(data.code);` return to you? I see no issue in why you can't access it. I hope the `dataType` is still present in the Ajax  function and you haven't removed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183587/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-vivek-23).

Comment: @vivek_23 I started a direct chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false`. This will exclude the plain-text header information from the response.

Comment: Awesome, I got rid of the header - now I just get the json object